# What country has the shortest history of human habitation?

Tags: exploration, migration, pacific-islanders

Feel free to interpret the question as referring to either **permanent human habitation** or **human habitation in general**.

Comment: Why did you tag this "pacific-islanders"? Are you expecting an answer in line with that tag?

Comment: And what about countries that only exist for a very brief period of time? Would that count?

Comment: Possibly, not necessarily, but it seems to be the only island related tag.

Comment: I mean a current country, considered as a territory. e.g. USA has been inhabited for thousands of years.

Comment: Does it have to be continuous? I can think of several islands that historically had other people on them, but were uninhabited when the present owners showed up. Also, would I be correct in assuming that autonomous regions/possessions of other countries (eg: Azores, Pitcairn, Greenland) wouldn't count?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'country', [Sealand](http://www.sealandgov.org/) might qualify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia has an article called [List of countries and islands by first human settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_islands_by_first_human_settlement). The latest by continuous habitation is [Crozet Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crozet_Islands), which was discovered in 1772 but was only intermittently inhabited (by sealers) until 1963 with the establishment of the [Alfred Faure research station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Faure). However it is part of France, which is obviously much older.

Another contender is [Antarctica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica), which did not have a permanent settlement until [1948](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_General_Bernardo_O%27Higgins_Riquelme). [By treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctic_Treaty_System) it does not belong to any country, but this also means it is not a country itself.

This leaves [Seychelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seychelles), which was first permanently settled in 1770 by France, then Britain, but gained independence in 1976.

Comment: Wow, somewhat surprised that exists. Looks like the Seychelles are the latest sovereign state at 1770.

Comment: Honorable mention to NZ at 1250 as the last major landmass.